# SQL Server count query comparing results to total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to return the number of distinct invoices that are fully rejected. An invoice can have multiple line items. If an invoice has a line item with reason '**None**' and another with '**Rejected**' then it is not fully rejected and should not be counted.

The result I want is as follows

```
Client     | No. of Invoices Fully Rejected
-------------------------------------------
Schogotten | 1
Maiken     | 2
```

Logically, I believe I return the number of invoices where the count of line items equals the count of invoices where the Reason is rejected per Invoice.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56d76/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Tmp (
  id int NOT NULL,
  client varchar (24) NOT NULL,
  invoice varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  statusid int NOT NULL,
  reason varchar (24)
)


INSERT INTO Tmp (id, client, invoice, statusid, reason) 
VALUES (12345, 'Schogotten', 'ABC12', -99, 'Rejected')
, (12346, 'Schogotten', 'ABC12', -99, 'None')
, (12347, 'Schogotten', 'ABC12', 10001, 'ReadyToPay')
, (12348, 'Schogotten', 'ABC11', -99, 'Rejected')
, (12349, 'Schogotten', 'ABC10', -99, 'None')
, (12350, 'Maiken', 'ABC13', -99, 'Rejected')
, (12351, 'Maiken', 'ABC14', 9006, 'ReadyToPay')
, (12351, 'Maiken', 'ABC14', -99, 'None')
, (12352, 'Maiken', 'ABC15', -99, 'Rejected');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Client
, COUNT(Invoice)
FROM Tmp
WHERE Reason = 'Rejected'
GROUP BY Client
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56d76/2/0)**:

```
|     CLIENT | COLUMN_1 |
|------------|----------|
|     Maiken |        2 |
| Schogotten |        2 |
```

Comment: Was you aware that SQL fiddle has a "Markdown Ouptut" option on the "Run SQL" button that you can simply paste into questions like above?

Comment: @Tanner I am now. Thanks for bringing to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a subquery to find the relevant invoices and then use an outer query to group by client:

```
select client,COUNT(*) from (
  select client,invoice
  from Tmp
  group by client,invoice
  having MIN(reason) = MAX(reason) and
  MIN(reason) = 'Rejected'
) t
group by client
```

Where hopefully the logic is straightforward to read - the subquery just finds invoices where all rows have the same value (`MIN(reason) = MAX(reason)`) where that reason is `Rejected` and then we just count them.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense and is the solution to my problem.